# How does the binomial theorem with negative $y$ work?

Tags: binomial-theorem

General formula the binomial theorem:
$(x+y)^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j$, but then what does this formula look like $(x - y)^n$ ?

More precisely, what her non-strict recording sequence looks like, and just as her strict recording using a sigma icon looks like.

I need this because I'm trying to understand the principle of adding two sequences with a binomial coefficient.
[image]

Comment: Note:  $(-y)^n=(-1)^ny^n$

Comment: $(x-y)^n = (x+(-y))^n = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}(-y)^j = \dots$

Comment: As an aside, "*How does the binomial theorem with negative $y$ work*" the answer is exactly the same as with positive $y$.  Nowhere in the formula do we make mention of the value or of the sign of $y$.  You mean to be asking "How does the binomial theorem work where we have subtraction in place of addition"

Comment: I would say $(x- y)= (x + (-y))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x - y = x+ (-y)= x+(-1)y$.

So $(x-y)^n =(x+(-y))^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}x^{n-j}(-y)^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j$

It is presumed to be understood that $(-1)^j$ is $-1$ if $j$ is odd and is $1$ if $j$ is even.

So in essence:  $(x- y)^n$ is much the same as $(x+y)^2$ but ever odd term is subtracted rather than added (and every even term is added).

So $(x+y)^n + (x-y)^n =\sum\limits_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j+  \sum\limits_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0}(1+(-1)^j){n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\begin{cases}2 & \text{if j is even}\\0 &\text{if j is odd}\end{cases}{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0;j \text{ is even}}^n2{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j$

$=$ "twice the even terms"

....

And $(x+y)^n - (x-y)^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j-  \sum\limits_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0}(1-(-1)^j){n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\begin{cases}0 & \text{if j is even}\\2 &\text{if j is odd}\end{cases}{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j=$

$\sum\limits_{j=0;j \text{ is odd}}^n2{n\choose j}x^{n-j}y^j$

$=$ "twice the odd terms"